# Oracle / SQL - summary table with grouped data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, data-mining

I have following raw data table:

| Account | Owner | Strategy | POSITION_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50001 | CompanyA | Equity | 1 |
| 50002 | CompanyA | Equity | 0 |
| 50002 | CompanyB | Fixed Income | 1 |

Now I want to produce summary table:

| X | Equity | Fixed Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CompanyA | 1/2 | 0/0 |
| CompanyB | 0/0 | 1/1 |

Columns: list of Strategies (I would have around 30 of them)

Rows: list of Owners (~100)

Cell value: string with two numbers: sum of POSITION_FLAG "/" count of rows from raw data table meeting criteria of row/column.

Would you be able to recommend how to do it?

Comment: Typical pivot question, answered many times, did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select owner,
    sum(case when strategy = 'Equity' and position_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
        || '/' 
        || sum(case when strategy = 'Equity' then 1 else 0 end) equity,
    sum(case when strategy = 'Fixed Income' and position_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
        || '/' 
        || sum(case when strategy = 'Fixed Income' then 1 else 0 end) fixed_income
from mytable
group by owner
```

Comment: OP says `Columns: list of Strategies (I would have around 30 of them)`, so they are dynamic.